# Angular-cli, karma Uncaught ReferenceError on global variables

Tags: angular, typescript, global-variables, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have an angular 4.0 project which was generated using angular-cli 1.0.

I have global variables such as api endpoints which are swapped based on environment in the deployment process by octopus deploy.

```
global-tokens.js

var apis = {
    foo: 'http://foobar.foo'
}
```

This behaves as expected served locally as well as in upper environments. But not when running unit tests.

I have tried including global tokens js in the `"files"` node in **tsconfig.spec.json** as well as in `"assets"` and `"scripts"`in **.angular.cli.json**.

When I run `ng test`, I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: apis is not defined

Upon further inspection, global-tokens.js is not included in index.html when I debug tests.

Any ideas as to how I might get that file into my environment?

**edit: added scripts attempt**

Comment: First, why not use the built it environment options in angular cli? if that's not desired, are those e2e tests or ui tests? have you tried adding this file via `.angular-cli.josn` `script` (like you would an external library)?

Comment: Edited in response to your comments. I have little control over the octopus process as far as which file is tokenized.

Comment: you can always do `require("path/to/global-tokens.js")` in your test case that is throwing Uncaught ReferenceError: apis is not defined. this will inline the global-tokens.jsin your test and the var becomes available.

Comment: Adding the require in the spec doesn't seem to solve the issue of the reference in the file under test. I continue to receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In **karma.conf.js** file, add **global-tokens.js** (*with appropriate path*) to **files** array

karma.config.js

```
config.set({
   ..
   files: ['global-tokens.js']
   ..
});
```